# Getting Xcode 4.6.3 to Autocomplete with right arrow key

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to make Xcode autocomplete when the right arrow key is pressed? I'm using Xcode 4.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default Control-Slash (^/) keyboard shortcut is used for "Select Next Placeholder" but you can redefine according to your comfort from `XCode > Preferences > Keybindings`
 you can also `tab` key for autocomplete step by step.